# is there any way to we can separate this "OR" (||) condition in if else condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, for-else

```
if(resellerContract.getStartDate() == null || 
                DateUtil.getDateInformat(DateUtil.YYY_MM_DD, resellerContract.getStartDate()).before(DateUtil.getDateInformat(DateUtil.YYY_MM_DD,new Date()))){
            validStartDate = false;
            logger.error("SPAC Start date is null");   
            validationErrors.add(new ValidationError(ResellerServiceErrorCode.SPAC_START_DATE_NULL));   
        }
```

i want to seperate validation for both differnt condtion how i can do that using if else or if if or what should i use because i want to send different error message

Comment: If you want react differently, you can make `if (cond1) { ... } else if (cond2) { ... }`. If you want to avoid code duplication, you can nest them: `if (cond1 || cond 2) { /* code for both cases */ if (cond1) { ... } else /* if (cond 2) */ { ... } }`

Comment: This is the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please focus your question on *what* you want to achieve - not on *how* you think it should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a "elseif" statement?

like e.g.:

```
if(resellerContract.getStartDate() == null) {
      ....
            validStartDate = false;
            logger.error("SPAC Start date is null");   
            validationErrors.add(new ValidationError(ResellerServiceErrorCode.SPAC_START_DATE_NULL));
 } else if (DateUtil.getDateInformat(DateUtil.YYY_MM_DD, resellerContract.getStartDate()).before(DateUtil.getDateInformat(DateUtil.YYY_MM_DD,new Date()))){
      ....
            validStartDate = false;
            logger.error("SPAC Start date is null");   
            validationErrors.add(new ValidationError(ResellerServiceErrorCode.SPAC_START_DATE_NULL));   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just separate the compound if statement into two if statements? Please clarify your intention; I feel that I may be giving you a trivial answer.

```
if (resellerContract.getStartDate() == null) {
    validStartDate = false;
    logger.error("SPAC Start date is null");   
    validationErrors.add(new ValidationError(ResellerServiceErrorCode.SPAC_START_DATE_NULL));   
}

if (DateUtil.getDateInformat(DateUtil.YYY_MM_DD, resellerContract.getStartDate())
            .before(DateUtil.getDateInformat(DateUtil.YYY_MM_DD,new Date()))) {
    //some other code
}
```